# Why did Virgin Galactic choose N2O / HTPB as its fuel?

Tags: rockets, crewed-spaceflight, tourism, virgin-galactic

It seems very exotic compared to something like RP1 or Methane, especially for a vehicle which should be flying a lot and around civilians. Why was this choice made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Virgin Galactic design was originally based on Burt Rutan's SpaceShipOne design.  Scaled Composites chose ("after a lengthy study") a N2O/HTPB hybrid motor for that vehicle because they felt it combined the handling simplicity of solid motors with the ability to terminate the thrust at will.

[Source](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/5226424/ns/technology_and_science-space/t/historic-rocket-powered-rubber-fuel/#.Wsa_0NYh1FQ)

Comment: I've just asked [Why did Virgin Galactic switch back to HTPB after one launch using thermoplastic polyamide (i.e. nylon)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26488/12102)